# Spring inject map issue

Tags: java, spring

I am seeing the below error which trying to inject a map into a bean. I am not sure how Spring is deducing that the map that I am trying to inject is of type org.apache.commons.collections.map.LinkedMap. How can I solve this issue?

> [org.apache.commons.collections.map.LinkedMap] to required type
>   [java.util.LinkedHashMap] for property 'asyncConnectorDaoMap'; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value
>   of type [org.apache.commons.collections.map.LinkedMap] to required
>   type [java.util.LinkedHashMap]

**Spring Config**

```
<bean id="fulfillment.management.AsyncConnectorFactory" class="com.service.async.AsyncConnectorFactory">      <property name="asyncConnectorDaoMap">         <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="com.service.async.AsyncConnectorDao">
                     <entry key="ACCOUNT_MANAGEMENT_CONTROLLER" value-ref="core.commons.AsyncConnectorDao"></entry>
                     <entry key="CUSTOMER_SERVICE" value-ref="core.commons.AsyncConnectorDao"></entry>
                     <entry key="ACCOUNT_SERVICE" value-ref="core.commons.AsyncConnectorDao"></entry>
                     <entry key="LOCATION_SERVICE" value-ref="core.commons.AsyncConnectorDao"></entry>        </map>       </property>  </bean>
```

**Code Below**

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;


public class AsyncConnectorFactory {

    private LinkedHashMap<String, AsyncConnectorDao> asyncConnectorDaoMap;

    public LinkedHashMap<String, AsyncConnectorDao> getAsyncConnectorDaoMap() {
        return asyncConnectorDaoMap;
    }

    public void setAsyncConnectorDaoMap(
            LinkedHashMap<String, AsyncConnectorDao> asyncConnectorDaoMap) {
        this.asyncConnectorDaoMap = asyncConnectorDaoMap;
    }

    public AsyncConnectorDao getAsyncConcurrentConnectorDao(String serviceIdentifier) {
        return asyncConnectorDaoMap.get(serviceIdentifier);
    }
}
```

**Modified Working Config**

```
    <bean id="fulfillment.management.AsyncConnectorFactory" class="com.service.async.AsyncConnectorFactory">
      <property name="asyncConnectorDaoMap" ref="asyncConnectorDaoMap1"/>
</bean> 

<util:map id="asyncConnectorDaoMap1" map-class="java.util.LinkedHashMap">
             <entry key="ACCOUNT_MANAGEMENT_CONTROLLER" value-ref="core.commons.AsyncConnectorDao"></entry>
             <entry key="CUSTOMER_SERVICE" value-ref="core.commons.AsyncConnectorDao"></entry>
             <entry key="ACCOUNT_SERVICE" value-ref="core.commons.AsyncConnectorDao"></entry>
             <entry key="LOCATION_SERVICE" value-ref="core.commons.AsyncConnectorDao"></entry>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to create the map first and then pass it as reference.

```
<util:map id="p:asyncConnectorDaoMap" map-class="java.util.LinkedHashMap">
    <entry key="ACCOUNT_MANAGEMENT_CONTROLLER" value-ref="asyncConnectorDao"/>
    <entry key="CUSTOMER_SERVICE" value-ref="asynConnectorService"/
</util:map>

<bean id="asyncConnectorDao" class="core.commons.AsyncConnectorDao" />
<bean id="asynConnectorService" class="core.commons.AsyncConnectorService" />


<bean id="fulfillment.management.AsyncConnectorFactory" class="com.service.async.AsyncConnectorFactory">      
    <property name="asyncConnectorDaoMap" ref="asyncConnectorDaoMap"/>       
</bean>
```

Be sure that your DAO and service beans are already created. Consider as well use [MapFactoryBean](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-mapfactorybean-example/)

Use the schema, for the use of util

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
```

Comment: Thanks Koitoer , is there anything wrong with the way I have defined?

Comment: I think the problem is in the value-ref, seems that you are pointing to a class instead of a bean

Comment: Thanks Kotoer , works now. I have pasted the working config.